# Как поставить пробел в cout? C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x, result, result1;
    cin >> x;
    result = x / 10;
    result1 = x % 10;
    cout << result;
    cout << result1 " " << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Перешёл на C++ с питона буквально пару дней назад, туплю иногда, но сейчас просто не знаю как сделать пробел в cout, чтобы в результате было - 2 3, а не 23. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cout << result << " " << result1 << endl;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.